# Pretrained computer vision models that accept as input a segmented image and the original image

Tags: python, image-classification, pytorch, computer-vision, image-segmentation

My data is a set of segmented images with extra details:
there is 30 object classes
each object is labeled with its state (very old, old-fashion, modern)
and each object is also labeled with a second state (broken, repaired, dirty, new)

I would like to fine-tune an object classifier on my private dataset using a model that accepts as input an image and its segment since my goal is not to learn how to segment the image but only the labels described above.

Is there some pre-trained models that accept as input an image (context) plus a segment of it?

Thanks!